# Is fetch_sub really atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference-counting, stdatomic

I have the following code (written in C++):

Code in StringRef class:

```
    inline void retain() const {
        m_refCount.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
    inline void release() const {
        if(m_refCount.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1){
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
            deleteFromParent();
        }
    }
```

Code in InternedString:

```
public:
    inline InternedString(){
        m_ref = nullptr;
    }
    inline InternedString(const InternedString& other){
        m_ref = other.m_ref;
        if(m_ref)
            m_ref->retain();
    }
    inline InternedString(InternedString&& other){
        m_ref = other.m_ref;
        other.m_ref = nullptr;
    }
    inline InternedString& operator=(const InternedString& other){
        if(&other == this)
            return *this;
        if(other.m_ref)
            other.m_ref->retain();
        if(m_ref)
            m_ref->release();
        m_ref = other.m_ref;
        return *this;
    }
    inline InternedString& operator=(InternedString&& other){
        if(&other == this)
            return *this;
        if(m_ref)
            m_ref->release();
        m_ref = other.m_ref;
        other.m_ref = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    /*! @group Destructors */
    inline ~InternedString(){
        if(m_ref)
            m_ref->release();
    }
private:
    inline InternedString(const StringRef* ref){
        assert(ref);
        m_ref = ref;
        m_ref->retain();
    }
```

When i execute this code in multiple threads deleteFromParent() gets called more than once for the same object. I don't understand why... Even if i am over releasing i should still not get this behaviour, i guess...

Can somebody help me? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch_sub` is as atomic as can be, but that's not the problem.

Try modifying your code like so:

```
    if(m_refCount.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1){
        Sleep(10);
        std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
        deleteFromParent();
```

and see what happens.

If your destructor gets preempted by a thread that makes use of your `InternedString` operators, they will happily and unknowingly get a reference to an object on the verge of deletion.
This means the rest of your code is free to reference deleted objects, leading to all sorts of UBs, including the possible re-incrementing of your perfectly atomic reference count leading to multiple perfectly atomic destructions.

Assuming anybody could copy references around without locking the destructor first is plain wrong, and only made worse if you bury it under the textbook perfect litany of operators needed to hide reference juggling from the end user.

If any task is free to delete your objects anytime, a bit of code like `InternedString a = b;` will simply have no way to know whether `b` is a valid object or not.
The reference count mechanism will work as intended only if all references have been set at a time the object was indeed valid.
What you can do is create as many `InternedString`<sub>s</sub> as you want in code sections where no deletion can occur in parallel (be it during init or through plain mutex locking), but once destructors are on the loose, that's it for reference juggling.

The only way to make that work without using mutexes or other synchronization objects would be to add a mechanism for acquiring a reference that would let the user know that the object has been deleted. Here is [an example of how that could be done](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/object-life-time-management/differential-reference-counting).

Now if you try to hide it all under a carpet of rule of five operators, the only remaining solution is to add some kind of `valid` attribute to your `InternedString`, that every bit of code would have to check before trying to access the underlying string.

This would amount to dumping the multitasking problems on the desk of your interface's end user, who would in the best case end up using mutexes to prevent other bits of code from deleting objects from under his feet, or maybe just tinker with the code until implicit synchronizations apparently took care of the problem, planting so many ticking time bombs in the application.

Atomic counters and/or structures are no replacement for multitasking synchronization.  Except for some experts who can design ultra smart algorithms, atomic variables are just a huge pitfall coated in tons of syntactic sugar.

Comment: i solved the problem... the problem is that i was resurrecting an object in the verge of the death. Since the deletion and resurrection is protected by the same spin lock, what was happening is that the object was resurrected and then later deleted because it's ref count reached zero. i solved the problem by just testing the ref-count for zero in the deletion of the object after locking the spin lock. thanks a lot.

Comment: Be aware that a spin lock might cause severe performance hits. You might consider using a plain old mutex instead. If you try both approaches and look at your perfmeter while running a test program, you will probably notice that the mutex causes a lot less CPU consumption. But of course it all depends how your test program excites your code.